# Android API 23 : cannot resolve FragmentActivity

Tags: android, android-fragmentactivity

I upgraded appcompat to rev 40 just now. After that, my project is throwing a compile error - it is not able to resolve FragmentActivity.

Build Target : API 23
Min : 16

Please let me know what I might be doing wrong. Appreciate your help.

Comment: which library you are using v4 or v7

Comment: I am using v7, do I need to use v4 too ? Am not clear about the diff - the "libs" folder had both android-support-v4.jar and android-support-v7-appcompat.jar, I included both in the Build path of the appcompat project and then built my project.

Comment: for fragments you need to use v4

Comment: import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;

Comment: @karthick: op asking for `FragmentActivity` not `Fragment`.

Comment: Sure, is there a version that I should import. Can I import the android-support-v4.jar itself that I found in the appcompat lib ?

Comment: @KrishnanVS r u using Eclipse or AStudio?

Comment: @KrishnanVS:  You don't need to import v4. Because when using v7, v4 is automagically included.

Comment: I am using Eclipse

Comment: @KrishnanVS:  isn't that AppCompat rev 40 is for API 25? So, did you using `compile com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.x.x`? If yes, then you need to change Target SDK, buildTools, and Compile SDK to API 25.

Comment: @KrishnanVS did u try with cleaning the project?

Comment: rev 40 was for API 23, that was why I just did the update. I tried cleaning as well.

Comment: Try this may will help you.Go to "File" -> "Invalidate Caches...", and select "Invalidate and Restart" option to fix this.

Comment: @sasikumar he is using Eclipse

Answer (score 2):

You should use `AppCompatActivity` because it is derived class of `FragmentActivity`

see the description below

```
java.lang.Object
   ↳    android.content.Context
       ↳    android.content.ContextWrapper
           ↳    android.view.ContextThemeWrapper
               ↳    android.app.Activity
                   ↳    android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity
                       ↳    android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all of you, for taking time to help me out. I took the lead from karchick and added an external reference to android-support-v4.jar that was present in the updated AppCompat project/libs and the error got resolved.

Comment: no need to use FragmentActivity , you should use AppCompactActivity which is derived class of FragmentActivity